# Running a Python Script to read info. from a new .txt file being generated at a known location every 1 sec

Tags: python, mysql, scripting

**My Scenario:** I have a known location(directory/path) where a .txt file is going to be generated every 1 sec, I just need to copy its content (contents are in a format which can be used directly to put in a MySQL query) and put it in a MySQL query in my Python script. I need to keep doing this continuously, i.e.,non-stop & always.

The script is something like:

```
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="IP_add", user="uname", passwd="pass", db="DB_name")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

#Need to add things below-

    sql = """INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('%d', 'dummy%d')""" % (i, i) //add what here ?

    cursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()


mydb.close()
```

**Problem:** I don't know how to go about making such a script running always, and have the MySQL connection open just once, while there goes on a constant scan of my known folder/directory/path to look for new text file and just keep reading info. it contains and put it into MySQL INSERT query. ***[A good thing is I don't need to format the text file's contents, just need to read whatever it contains.]***

Please Help !

Regards,
Chirayu

Comment: What creates the file? If this is *nix, you can create a pipe file and just read off one end while whatever writes the data writes to it

Comment: @tMC,well data is being created in a linux based machine, can you give a link for this pipe file you re talking about ?

Comment: `man mkfifo` beware, when a process opens the file for writing, it will block until another process opens it for reading.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import time
from stat import ST_MTIME

TIME_TO_SLEEP = 1          # to avoid CPU burning

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="IP_add", user="uname", passwd="pass", db="DB_name")
cursor = mydb.cursor()
last_date = 0
while True:                        # or what you want as stop condition
    time.sleep(TIME_TO_SLEEP)
    stat = os.stat(filename)
    if stat[ST_MTIME] > last_date: # check the last modification date
        last_date = stat[ST_MTIME] # if more recent, store the last date
        with open(filename) as f:   # open the file
            sql = f.read()         # put the content in the sql data base
            if sql:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                mydb.commit()

mydb.close()
```

Comment: @Cedric, thanks a,lot for replying..your code seems right, but I had 2 questions -
**1)** If I want to look for any new file at a particular location, and then do what you have given (i.e., look for latest 'filename' according to your code), how to do that ?
**2)** How to specify the path for filename in - os.stat(filename) ?

Sorry if my questions come across as naive, but I have almost no Python experience, and need this to get my Project working.

Comment: @Cédric: well done; you may want to add a time.sleep(1) in the loop to avoid pegging the CPU.

Comment: @Cedric & others, I get an error at - with open("query.txt") as f: , and it underlines word open and says erro in syntax:invalid syntax...help !

Comment: if your python version is < 2.5, the with statement is unknown, replace it with : `f = open(filename)` sql stuff... then `f.close()`

Comment: @Cedric, it worked..thanks a lot, have 1 question, Qs. 1) of my first comment, acording to your code, if stop condition is while(true), now when I run this script, it keeps on running, possibly looking for changes in filename, but if I make any change in the same file, the script stops and gives error as given in my next comment (character limit in this comment) :P !

Comment: the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yourscript_db.py", line 15, in ?
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1065, 'Query was empty')
`

Comment: I had a test to check the length of the file content : `if sql:` this will avoid the sql exception

Comment: @Cedric, it works & it works like a charm....I'm very thankful to you, as it could not have been possible without you help at each step..hopefully I have not bugged you to the level that you never answer my next Python question ...once again, I'm very-very thankful !!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the MySQL command. `Load data infile`.

This will do what you want much, much faster than individual inserts will do, plus you don't need any perl code to read the lines.

**Example**

```
sql = """LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/test/test1.txt' INTO TABLE table1"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Load data infile has lots of options for field and line separators, check it out at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

To load a file that contains

```
6666, 'test'
```

use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/test.txt' INTO TABLE `test` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Note the use of forward slashes on file paths *(even on Windows)* and the `'\''` to put a single quote inside two quotes `'`. The line terminator is correct for Windows, Linux would need `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.

**If you're really lazy**
Make a MySQL event.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT import_file       
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE                 
DO BEGIN
  LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/test.txt' INTO TABLE `test` IGNORE 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The `IGNORE` keyword will skip over fields that trigger a primary or unique key violation, so that it will not try and import those entries.
Define the proper field as unique to prevent MySQL from importing duplicate entries.

For more info on events
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: @Johan, I was trying your method for just 1 constant text file at known location, get an error, think you might resolve it easily..
my text file only contains - 6666, 'kool' , I get an error from saying wrong mysql syntax near table1...help !

Comment: @Chirayu, forgot the `TABLE` keyword, fixed the answer.

Comment: @Johan, thanks for the edit..my file contains data as you stated, this file is stored in the same folder as where the python script is, and this is a linux machine..the connection to MySQL is remote, i.e., MySQL is stored on a remote windows machine..here is my script

`import MySQLdb
import os

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="11.40.3.167", user="anad", passwd="anad", db="trial1")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = """LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt' INTO TABLE `intrial1`"""
cursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()

mydb.close()
`
I get an error, which is in next comment.

Comment: I get the error: 

`_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (29, "File 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\Data\\trial1\\test.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)")
`

Comment: use **forward slashes even on Windows** and specify the full path, otherwise a path relative to the datastore will be used.